# How to set the java path and classpath in windows-64bit

Tags: java, classpath

I have installed java on windows-64bit OS. but when I execute javac, it is failing with the

error message no such command is available". I have created following environmental variable

CLASSPATH    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\lib

Comment: I wouldn't install such an old version of Java.  I would also install the 64-bit Java on a 64-bit OS.  Why do you want to run `javac` on the command line?  I would use an IDE, its more productive/easier.  If you really want to do this, there are loads of pages on how to do this on the web, I would search for one.

Comment: @Peter Because running Java on the command line is more educational, and Ant/Maven runs on the command line, and projects should be tested to be IDE-neutral, because they need that specific version of Java, etc.

Comment: You have asked 21 questions and not accepted a single answer.  Why?

Comment: @Dave, You have to crawl before you can walk, I was wondering if he really had to crawl. Ant/Maven also runs in IDEs and CI servers. You generally don't need to run them on the command line either.  I would hope that running `javac` is IDE neutral.  If you have a project which need Java 6 update 5 specifically, you have done something seriously wrong IMHO.

Comment: For the first two years I did development, I only did machine programming, using hex values.  It taught me a lot about computer hardware.  However I wouldn't recommend this approach for anyone else because its likely to be a waste of your time (mostly)

Comment: @Peter, some people like to match their dev environment to their deploy environment--those that don't are doing something seriously wrong, or at least risky. Some IDEs support Maven better than others. A cmdline build is what CI servers use, so you need to be able to do it, and understand it. And while two years of *actual* machine code programming *is* a waste of time, two years of low-level assembly and C likely is *not*. At least you got to use hex; my byte-code programming days were in octal.

Answer (score 7):

Add the appropriate javac path to your PATH variable.  `java.exe` will be found under the `bin` directory of your JDK. E.g.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin
```

Answer (score 6):

Before answering your question, just wann ans this simple question : **Why we need PATH and CLASSPATH?**

**Answer:**

1) **PATH:** You need to set PATH to compile Java source code, create JAVA CLASS FILES and Operating System to load classes at runtime.

2) **CLASSPATH:** This is used by JVM and not by OS.

Answer to your question :

Just make sure you have Modified **PATH** variable (Windows System Environmental Variable) so that it points to bin dir which contains all exe for example: java,javac and etc. In my case it is like this : **;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin**.

**So, it doesn't matter your system is 32 bit/64 bit until and unless you specify/Modify the PATH variable correctly.**

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the most conventional way of getting it done on Windows is

- Go to Control Panel
- Click System
- Open Advanced settings
- Click Environment Variables...

Path is one of the variables under "System Variables". 
This is where the system will search when you try to execute a command.

- just append the full path to the Bin folder under your Java
  installation path. You can copy it using Windows Explorer to avoid typing it manually
- click OK to close the dialogs.

To verify, open the command window aka console window (for example, WindowsKey-R cmd.exe ) and run:

```
javac -version
```

If the java bin folder is in the path, the system will find and execute the javac.exe file located there, and you will see your Java version. Something like:

```
c:\>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_65
```

Answer (score 1):

**Very Simple:**

You need to set the two environment variables only; **PATH** and **java**

=>Right Click on **My computer**

=>**Properties**

=>Click on left hand side bar menu "**Advanced system settings**"
=> Click on "**Environment Variables**" button refer below fig.

[image]

=>Follow the below steps to Set **User variable** and **System variable**.

To Set **User variable** named as "**PATH**"

- Click on "**New**" button in **user variables** section.
- Set the **variable name** as "**PATH**" and variable value as per your java
  installed version.(Shown in below fig.)

To Set **System variable** named as "**java**"

- Click on "New" button in System variable tab.
- Set the variable name as "**java**" and variable value as per your java
  installed version.(Shown in below fig.)
  Refer below images for the reference.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the 'JAVA_HOME' variable should be set as a System Variable, instead of User Variable. 
When the 'JAVA_HOME' was changed to be a System Variable, the command 'javac' works.
Also, the PATH and CLASSPATH are System Variable.